# RobotFramework / Selenium: How to set screenshot-name to testcase-name on failure

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I was wondering if there is a possibility to make the following happen. Let's say I have 3 Testcases with the following results in RIDE:

```
Testcase Easter  --  PASS
Testcase Christmas  --  FAIL
Testcase Foo  --  PASS
```

I want to take a screenshot which should be named testcase_christmas.png (or with ' ' instead of '_', that does not matter). Is there a possibility to do it dynamically, something like

```
${testcase}=    Get Testcase Name
Capture Page Screenshot    ${testcase}
```

or anything like that? I am using:

- Python 2.7.x (latest) 32 bit
- wxPython 2.8 32 bit
- geckodriver latest 64 bit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Robot framework automatically sets the variable `${TEST NAME}` to contain the name of the currently executing test. See [Automatic Variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#automatic-variables) in the user guide)

The documentation for SeleniumLibrary's [Capture Page Screenshot](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Capture%20Page%20Screenshot) shows that you can give it a filename as the first argument.

Putting those two together, you can do this:

```
Capture page screenshot  ${TEST NAME}.png
```

Comment: ty, was really helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

The way I would go about this is creating a test teardown and using automatic variables form robot framework. Found here: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#automatic-variables

Your keywords page / resource file should have a load test data keyword that gets the test name, along with setting a test variable you can assign the screenshot too.

```
*** Keywords ***
Load Test Data
    ${data}    Get File    ${TEST NAME}.txt
    Set Test Variable    ${data}    ${data}

Common Test Teardown
    capture page screenshot    ${data}.png
```

Your test should call whatever test teardown you decide to use.

```
*** Settings ***
Test Setup    Load Test Data

*** Testcases ***
Test Case A
    My keywords
    [Teardown]    Common Test Teardown
```

Calling the test setup allows you to load the name of each test in your file and in the teardown if it fails will take a screenshot with the test case name you loaded in your test setup.

Comment: ty again, got a little bit knowledge during the answer, but implemented the faster one above

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the screenshots on basis of test case ie. a separate folder for all  screenshots related to each test case. Then you can use:

`Set Screenshot Directory         ./Screenshots/${SUITE NAME}/${TEST NAME}`

Capture Page Screenshot    ABC.png

A Screenshot directory will be created in the project root folder where all the screenshots will be stored in different folders based on the test case and test suites.

For a single suite you can use

```
Set Screenshot Directory         ./Screenshots/${TEST NAME}
```